# JavaFx : Adding data from multiple classes to a tableView

Tags: javafx-2

I am developing a billing application in which the user enters the product and quantity using text fields into a tableView. I want the tableView to generate the total cost(product price X quantity) and display it in a third column. I am having an entity class named Cart which contains fields for product and quantity and the method for finding the total cost resided in another class called CartManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html)

Specifically, your Cart should contain a field DoubleProperty or IntegerProperty.
The code would look something like this:

```
DoubleProperty cost = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
cost.bind(quantity.multiply(price));
```

quantity and price should already be Double-/IntegerProperties if they are shown in the TableView. The cost should be shown in the TableView the same way as quantity and price.

Comment: You could also do this directly in the `TableColumn`, without having a cost property in the `Cart`. Just set a `cellValueFactory` on the cost column whose `call(...)` method returns `quantity.multiply(price)`